# Adding 'Silverlight 5' as target to VS2013 PCL project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2013, portable-class-library

**Problem:**

When I add 'Silverlight 5' as a target to my PCL project, the compiler can no longer find System.Collections.Specialized.

**Tools:**

- Visual Studio 2013
- Xamarin 3.11.837 (not sure it matters)

**Setup:**

- Create a new C# Portable Class Library project:

  - In Class1.cs (1-line): `using System.Collections.Specialized;`
- Targets:

  - .NET 4.5;
  - Windows 8;
  - Windows Phone 8.1
- Add the target:

  - Go to Project->Properties->Targets
  - Add "Silverlight 5" as target
  - `Specialized` can no longer be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason that is not immediately obvious, the `System.Collections.Specialized` namespace is not included in PCL Profile 255 (.NET 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1, Silverlight 5), as you have painfully observed.

It **is** included in PCL Profile 158 (.NET 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone *Silverlight* 8, Silverlight 5) however, so if it is an option for you to sacrifice the *Windows Phone 8.1* platform, you should be fine.

Comment: Ah, so if I read you correctly, the chosen permutation of target platforms determines the "PCL Profile", which in-turn determines which libs and namespaces are available. Thx!